# Using selection sort on a generic linked list in c

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, selection-sort

I have a generic linked list that is doubly linked.  I am trying to sort whatever the list's node data might be.  I have this selection sort working when sorting an array of `ints`, but modifying it to sort the linked list, it fails to sort.  Here is enough code from various .c files to test the sort. I'm testing with a list of `ints`.  I was thinking it would be easier to only swap the data in the nodes versus swapping the whole nodes and needing to reset the `node->next` and `node->prev` of each.  Much thanks for your help in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    void * data;
    struct node * next;
    struct node * prev;
};
typedef struct node Node;

struct linkedlist
{
    Node * head;
    int size;
};
typedef struct linkedlist LinkedList;

struct my_int
{
    int value;
};
typedef struct my_int MyInt;

LinkedList * linkedList()
{
    LinkedList * list = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    list->head = malloc(sizeof(Node)); // Dummy head node
    list->size = 0;
    return list;
}

// function pointer to compare node data of int
int compareInt(const void * p1, const void * p2)
{
    if(p1 == NULL || p2 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Method compareInt() failed - NULL parameter");
        exit(-99);
    }
    MyInt * int1 = (MyInt*)p1;
    MyInt * int2 = (MyInt*)p2;
    if(int1 < int2)
        return -1;
    if(int1 > int2)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void addFirst(LinkedList * theList, int data)
{
    if(theList == NULL)
    }
        perror("Call to addFirst() failed - passed in LinkedList * was NULL\n");
        exit(-99);
    }
    Node * nn = (Node*)calloc(1,sizeof(Node));
    nn->next = theList->head->next;
    theList->head->next = nn;
    nn->prev = theList->head;
    nn->data = data;
    theList->size = theList->size + 1;
}

void sort(LinkedList * theList, int (*compare)(const void *, const void *))
{
    Node * cur = theList->head->next;
    Node * temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    for(; cur->next != NULL; cur = cur->next)
    {
        Node * minNode = cur;
        for(Node * j = cur->next; j != NULL; j = j->next)
        {
            if(compare(j, minNode) < 0)
                minNode = j;
        }
        temp->data = minNode->data;
        minNode->data = cur->data;
        cur->data = temp->data;
    }
    free(temp);
}

// Driver to test the sort
int main()
{
    LinkedList * intList = linkedList();
    addFirst(intList,3);
    addFirst(intList,5);
    addFirst(intList,4);
    addFirst(intList,1);
    addFirst(intList,2);

    Node * cur = intList->head->next;
    while(cur != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n",cur->data);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    printf("\n");

    sort(intList, compareInt);

    cur = intList->head->next;
    while(cur != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n",cur->data);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance in your compareInt function you are comparing pointers rather than the values that they point to:

```
MyInt * int1 = (MyInt*)p1;
MyInt * int2 = (MyInt*)p2;
if(int1 < int2)
```

I think you need:

```
if (*int1 < *int2) etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

in the compareInt function I wasn't comparing the actual data.  I solved this by doing:

```
MyInt * intNode1 = (MyInt*)p1;
MyInt * intNode2 = (MyInt*)p2;
int int1 = intNode1->value;
int int2 = intNode2->value;
```

also in the sort function, passing the pointer to the data, not the node, into the compare function like so:

```
if(compare(j->data, minNode->data) < 0)
```

Comment: I find it a bit lame that you wrote your own answer after I told you the exact same thing in my answer. Not cool.